# Inner join condition is disregarded - looks like an Oracle bug

Tags: sql, oracle, join, parameters, conditional-statements

How is this possible?: If I replace message_format_name with the literal 'MT202', the query works as expected. Otherwise, it returns 2 rows instead of the expected 1--same as if that condition was commented out.

It seems the parameter value passed in to the stored proc doesn't equal the value in ms.message_format_name for some strange reason.

Let me know if you need more details.
Thanks!

```
set define off;
create or replace PROCEDURE          insert_mapping(
        interface_name        IN VARCHAR2,
        message_format_name   IN VARCHAR2,
        determined_field_type IN VARCHAR2,
        source_field          IN VARCHAR2,
        mapping_key           IN VARCHAR2,
        mapping_key_value1    IN VARCHAR2,
        mapping_key_value2    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
        return_val OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('interface_name = ' || interface_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('message_format_name = ' || message_format_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('determined_field_type = ' || determined_field_type);
    dbms_output.put_line('source_field = ' || source_field);
/*  INSERT
    INTO payments.multi_value_lookup_mapping
        (
            pk_multi_value_lkp_mapping,
            fk_pk_multi_value_lookup_confg,
            mapping_key,
            mapping_key_value1,
            mapping_key_value2,
            created_by,
            created_dt,
            update_by,
            update_dt
        )*/
    OPEN return_val FOR        
    SELECT payments.seq_multi_value_lookup_map.nextval,
        mvlc.pk_multi_value_lookup_config,
        mapping_key,
        mapping_key_value1,
        mapping_key_value2,
        50000,
        SYSDATE,
        50000,
        SYSDATE
    FROM payments.multi_value_lookup_config mvlc, payments.message_source ms
    WHERE  (ms.pk_message_source      = mvlc.fk_pk_message_source
        AND ms.interface_name         = interface_name
        AND ms.message_format_name    = message_format_name /*'MT202'*/
        AND mvlc.mapping_column_name  = source_field
        AND mvlc.lookup_category_type = determined_field_type
        );

END insert_mapping;
```

Comment: @Aleksej yes, I believe that I know nothing about oracle :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an Oracle bug.  First, you should *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  You should *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

But that is not your specific problem.  Variable resolution and scoping is.

When you have a reference such as `interface_name` in a query, then Oracle looks first for columns with that name.  It never sees the variables.  Name the variables something distinguishing, so you end up with code that is more like this:

```
   . . .
   FROM payments.multi_value_lookup_config mvlc JOIN
        payments.message_source ms
        ON  ms.pk_message_source = mvlc.fk_pk_message_source 
   WHERE  ms.interface_name = v_interface_name
          ms.message_format_name = v_message_format_name /*'MT202'*/
          mvlc.mapping_column_name  = v_source_field
          mvlc.lookup_category_type = v_determined_field_type
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon! That was it. (The query was written in ANSI format originally btw, this form is just one of the things I tried).

Comment: Another way to resolve the scoping issues is to prepend the function/procedure name to the parameter e.g. `ms.message_format_name = insert_mapping.message_format_name` however, it's definitely easier just to avoid the scoping issue altogether.